# How to find an XML file with a particular name

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python and trying to fetch an XML file from a list of files using regular expressions, but I've never used regular expressions until now.

Suppose I had a list of files:

```
files = ['.bash_logout', '20120910NYP.xml', '.bash_profile', '.bashrc', '.mozilla', 'testfile_248.xml']
```

Now I need to fetch the file of format `20120910NYP.xml` so I decided to write a regular expression:

```
import re
feedRegex = # ?
feedFiles = filter((lambda x: re.search(feedRegEx, x) != None), files)
```

In the above code, how would I write a regular expression for `feedRegex` to find XML files in that format from the list?

Edited Code:

Need to give `list of files` and `feedregex` code to this function every time i need this function

```
import re

def paramikoFetchLatestFeedFile(list_of_files, feedRegEx):

    self.files = list_of_files
    self.feedRegEx = feedRegEx

    feedFiles = filter((lambda x: re.search(self.feedRegEx, x) != None), self.files)
```

Comment: And apart from that: why do you assign self.files and self.feddRegEx inside a simple method which is not a class method? You really don't know the Python basics.

Comment: Requesting to close the question as poor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you want something like

```
regex = re.compile('^\d{8}.NYP.xml$')
```

Please read the regular expressions documentation. This is truly regex basics.

Comment: please look at my edited code above

Comment: Nothing to look at. This information is good enough in order to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

```
files = [...]
xml_files = [fn for fn in files if fn.endswith('.xml')]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need only the file with format 20120910NYP from the list

Comment: No idea what you really want. If want to check if something is in side a list: use the 'in' operator....and read the Python tutorial...this is Python basics.

Comment: sorry u had misunderstood me, if u see clearly i want the files from the list with format yyyymmddNYP.xml, because there may be more files in the list with this format with different dates, so i want to fetch xml files of the format above.

Comment: Should we smell that you want to filter out files by some date format? What have you tried so far? What is the regex you tried?

Comment: Update your question properly

Comment: Thanks actually i was stuck in using regex operators so trying to find the basics in filter a file starting with numbers followed by NYP. I mean to write regex like files starting with numbers(20122010) followed by NYP witha n extension of .xml

Answer (score 0):

Use [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) to do the filtering for you.

Suppose you have this directory:

```
burhan@sandbox:~/t$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 burhan burhan 0 Sep 11 09:17 20120101NYP.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 burhan burhan 0 Sep 11 09:08 20120819ABC.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 burhan burhan 0 Sep 11 09:09 ABC10234ABC.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 burhan burhan 0 Sep 11 09:15 bar.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 burhan burhan 0 Sep 11 09:15 blablah.gif
-rw-r--r-- 1 burhan burhan 0 Sep 11 09:15 foo.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 burhan burhan 0 Sep 11 09:15 hello.jpg
```

Here is how you would filter it:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob("[0-9]*NYP.xml")
['20120101NYP.xml']
```

For your specific requirement:

```
>>> import re
>>> file_list = ['20121011NYP.xml','foo.bar','zoo.txt','ABC1234.xml','20120101ABC.XML']
>>> exp = re.compile('^\d{8}NYP\.xml$', re.I)
>>> filtered_list = [x for x in file_list if re.match(exp,x)]
>>> filtered_list
['20121011NYP.xml']
```

Comment: Wow that some what near to my need. But i need to to perform this using regex, because i had written a function which takes a feedregex(regex code to filter a file) and list of files. Now need to filter the files with the feedRegex code and return all the files, so i had to use the function many times.

Comment: please look at my edited code above

Comment: Read the other answers and please check the regular expression documentation. Building a regular expression for your case can be done by yourself by a little motivation trying out things yourself. If you have problems with a particular regex then ask about that particular problem what don't expect that we're doing your homework and present it to you on a golden plate.

Comment: @Kouripm in the future, please state your complete requirements directly in the question.